# How can I un-trim a trimmed voice memo?

Tags: iphone, audio, voice-memo

I recently recorded an interview on my iPhone 4, however i trimmed it (before syncing with my computer) and shared the trimmed section with a friend. Is there any way I can get the full voice memo back?

Answer (score 1):

Today I used the free software [iBrowse](https://www.ibrowseapp.com/) on my Mac (PC version also available) to view my iPhone 5 file sytem. I opened the Recordings folder and found all my Voice Memos.

The interesting part is, a Voice Memo I had Trimmed and sent to someone via iMessage, was there in both its original filename and full size, as well as another copy with .trimmed appended to its filename, evidently this is the shortened version I sent my friend.

So if you use iBrowse to view your Recordings, there's a good chance you'll find your original Voice Memo inside there.

PS: I am using iOS 6.1.4 on my iPhone 5.

Comment: iBrowse is **not** a free software, and it's part of [iexplorer](https://www.macroplant.com/iexplorer/), FYI

Answer (score -1):

No. You cannot get the full version back.

Answer (score -1):

Yes u can't , I tried before,
U just can find the one 0B .
Go to ver/mobile/media/recordings and look for it by date